# Heroku: Apigee for Twitter add-on

Tags: heroku, twitter, apigee

I am trying to use apigee for Twitter add-on in Heroku, but I get this message

That add-on is only available to selected users

What I have to do?

Thanks

PS: Is this add-on working with Twitter API v1.1?

Comment: Something is definitely up with the Apigee add-on. It is no longer listed in the Add-on section of the Heroku site, and it is marked as "deprecated" on any existing Heroku apps that had previously installed it.

Comment: Thank you Gus, so is there any chance to use apigee for twitter in heroku without using the add-on?

Comment: take a look at Tim's support link below (the second one). And you may also want to mark his answer as the solution to your question :)

Answer (score 5):

Tim from Apigee here. I can confirm that our Apigee for Twitter (and Apigee for Facebook) add-ons have been deprecated. Heroku apps that have already provisioned the add-ons can keep using them but we are not accepting any new users at this time.

That said, you don’t necessarily need the add-ons; you may be able to get the same functionalities you are looking for through the new Apigee platform. You can [sign up and use it for free](http://enterprise.apigee.com/signup) and very quickly have it proxy the Twitter API by following our [quickstarts](http://apigee.com/docs/enterprise/quickstarts).

If you have any more questions, please feel free to post them on SO and I’ll make sure someone gives you a prompt answer.

Comment: +1 for disclosing affiliation *and* supporting your users via SO!

Comment: I have been reading the docs but I think they are complicated.

Dou you have some coding sample to work with Twitter API v1.1 in heroku using apigee?

Thanks

Comment: @jferrercas Are you on http://support.apigee.com/apigee/topics/is_the_apigee_twitter_api_working_with_twitter_api_v_1_1 ? Someone should be able to give you some sample code there.

Comment: A full detail on what you can get out of proxying Twitter with Apigee has been posted here: http://support.apigee.com/apigee/topics/how_to_configure_apigee_for_twitter_in_heroku_without_using_add_on#reply_10387674 I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for passing on that info Tim, and for the support link related to configuring Apigee for Twitter on Heroku.Is there any particular reason why there have been no announcements on Heroku or Apigee about this?